# Lightning Web Component Specialist Super badge: Challenge 7 throwing error

Tags: lwc

I am facing error in LWC Specialist Superbadge Challenge:7

```js
import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import getBoatsByLocation from '@salesforce/apex/BoatDataService.getBoatsByLocation';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

const LABEL_YOU_ARE_HERE = 'You are here!';
const ICON_STANDARD_USER = 'standard:user';
const ERROR_TITLE = 'Error loading Boats Near Me';
const ERROR_VARIANT = 'error';
export default class BoatsNearMe extends LightningElement {
    @api boatTypeId;
    @track mapMarkers = [];
    @track isLoading = true;
    @track isRendered = false;
    latitude;
    longitude;
    @wire(getBoatsByLocation, { latitude: '$latitude', longitude: '$longitude', boatTypeId: '$boatTypeId' })
    wiredBoatsJSON({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.createMapMarkers(data);
        } else if (error) {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: ERROR_TITLE,
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: ERROR_VARIANT
                })
            );
            this.isLoading = false;
        }
    }
    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.isRendered == false) {
            this.getLocationFromBrowser();
        }
        this.isRendered = true;
    }
    getLocationFromBrowser() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            position => {
                this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            },
            (e) => {

            }, {
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        }
        );
    }
    createMapMarkers(boatData) {
        this.mapMarkers = JSON.parse(boatData).map(rowBoat => {
            return {
                location: {
                    Latitude: rowBoat.Geolocation__Latitude_s,
                    Longitude: rowBoat.Geolocation__Longitude_s
                },
                title: rowBoat.Name,
            };
        });
        this.mapMarkers.unshift({
            location: {
                Latitude: this.latitude,
                Longitude: this.longitude
            },
            title: LABEL_YOU_ARE_HERE,
            icon: ICON_STANDARD_USER
        });
        this.isLoading = false;
    }
}
```

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card class="slds-is-relative">
        <template if:true={isLoading}>
            <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="small" variant="brand"></lightning-spinner>
        </template>    
       <!-- The lightning-map goes here -->
       <template if:true={isRendered}>
            <lightning-map map-markers={mapMarkers}> </lightning-map>
       </template>
       <div slot="footer">Top 10 Only!</div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong: We can't find the correct settings for the `createMapMarkers()` function in the component boatsNearMe JavaScript file. Make sure the component was created according to the requirements, including the right `mapMarkers`, title, Latitude (`Geolocation__Latitude__s`), Longitude (`Geolocation__Longitude__s`), the correct constants, stopping the loading spinner, and using the proper case-sensitivity and consistent quotation.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign newMarkers to mapMarkers.

```
    newMarkers.unshift({
    location: {
        Latitude: this.latitude,
        Longitude: this.longitude
    },
    title: LABEL_YOU_ARE_HERE,
    icon: ICON_STANDARD_USER
});

this.mapMarkers = newMarkers;
this.isLoading = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

In createMapMarkers method Double underscore is missing. Try:

```
                Latitude: rowBoat.Geolocation__Latitude__s,
                Longitude: rowBoat.Geolocation_Longitude__s
```